# ASP.NET web app is completely hung; even restarting IIS won't fix it

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET web app which is running in a local instance of IIS. Something caused the app to hang, and it now is completely hung - even if I restart IIS and navigate to the home page (it wasn't the home page that caused the hang), it doesn't respond but doesn't time out either. What do I need to reset to get my web app up and running again? I don't see anything fishy in Event Viewer... also, I tried rebooting my PC and even that didn't help!

Comment: Hmmm...you might take a look at your logs to see if you're getting some (obviously) unintentional perpetual redirects. Look for a long log of "302" codes (log entries with an HTTP result of 302) that might be bouncing right back to the same site. That *might* explain the "never returns, but never times out" issue. Sometimes that will happen in error handling code, too. Just a thought.

Comment: Hmm, I do have a lot of 302 codes, but they are all redirecting me to an error page, not the page I was on, which makes sense because I was trying to fix all the errors in that page.

Comment: Wait a second... There's no entry for the home page which I'm trying to access! The most recent log entry is for the page I was testing; it was a 200, so it did load successfully for once. But the home page I'm trying to access now is not appearing...

Comment: That would make me suspect that an error is firing, then error handling code is 302'ing to the error page itself, and *that* page is either invoking a new request or generating an error on its own. If you have custom error handling, you  might temporarily disable/remove it and see if you can force the app to crash in a manner that would allow you to inspect the failure mode.

Comment: Is the "home" page you are trying to access defined as a "Default" page within IIS, or is it something defined by code in your startup? Sounds like you might be getting some clues! :)

Comment: The home page I'm trying to access is at the following URL: http://localhost:3878/Admin - so I guess it's a default page because this is a WebForms app so there's no sort of MVC style URL rewriting going on. I guess I could attach a debugger and set a breakpoint in the Admin/index.aspx or whatever the default page is...

Comment: I'd make sure your error handling was disabled for the moment, and then allow the app to run and fail and show you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205472/discussion-between-ekolis-and-david-w).

Comment: Please learn tools such as Telerik Fiddler and IIS failed request tracing. With them you can tell yourself whether the culprit is "the browser didn't send the right requests" or "the IIS server didn't respond properly". For you, it is too early to say IIS hung, as if restarting IIS and rebooting Windows do not help, then that's not a typical IIS hang scenario.

Comment: Did you see any error message in C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR log? First of all, you need to make sure your server has received this request. Please ensure you could find that request in either worker process monitor or httperr log.